# Html Email don't work well on Android

Tags: android, html, email

Please take a look to my code and tell me if there is something wrong.
It's an Html email.
It work perfectly on all devices but not in Android I'm searching since two days now and still don't know why.

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content=" text/watch-html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Email</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<body><!--[if IE]>
      <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial, sans-serif;height: 748px; padding: 280px 90px 100px; background-image: url(https://image.jpg);" width="600">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size: 20px; color:#415ca7;height: 100px;"> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="height: 10px;">
            <hr style="height:3px; background-color:#d01d1b; width: 40px; float:left;border:none;" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size: 15px; color:#415ca7;height: 120px;padding-bottom: 50px;"> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="button" style="background-color: #d01d1b;border-radius: 5px;text-align: center;padding: 10px 20px;line-height: 40px;display: block;margin: 0 auto;width: 200px;"><a href="#" style="color: #ffffff;display: block;font-size: 14px;text-decoration: none;text-transform: uppercase;" target="_blank">LINK</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im assuming that it just does not look good on android phones?  That is a very common issue.  [This](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2012/02/why-cant-i-get-my-html-email-to-look-great-on-android-devices/) article goes into a little detail. But basically you should have a fluid layout that can adjust to many screen sizes.

CSS also sometimes does not play nice with android. [Here](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) is a list of CSS properties and their compatability with android.

Comment: Hi Marjorie and thanks for the help. Yes the email do not display good on Android. Actually it's kind of too zoomed. I red the articles but I didn't found a solution... :)

Comment: Sorry a little update Marjorie. I was wrong your links were very helpful for fluid layout side + the background image we shoud to add a background-size: contain;

Comment: I am glad they helped!

Comment: C'est fait et encore milles merci ;)